# Is there an XSLT 2.0 library for .NET?

Tags: .net, xslt, xslt-2.0

Simple query - I am looking for recommendations for a .NET library that supports XSLT 2.0 (if one exists).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/), or the Altova engine which powers XMLSpy is also available for free [directly from them](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html).

Comment: It should be noted that neither is strictly native. Saxon is written in Java, and cross-compiled to .NET using IKVM. Consequently, you have to distribute IKVM runtime (which is mostly a bunch of Java classes recompiled for .NET), which is fairly large. But at least it's all managed code in the end. Altova is a COM component, so you get all the wonders (and perf) of COM interop, and installation hassles as well; and, of course, your code will need FullTrust. I'd recommend Saxon - it is pure managed, and performance-wise it is still better.

Comment: I have seen poor application domain load issues with Saxon.NET.  The loading of the JVM and Java Class libraries (IKVM) takes time and consumes what I would call a significant amount of memory (my recollection is ~90MB).  This might not be critical for a client application but for web servers, this creates a noticable lag in request response time (several seconds) at application start up.  I have identified those performance issues impact the Ektron CMS product which uses Saxon.

Answer (score 2):

[XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp.com) is a native XSLT 2.0 and XQuery processor for .NET