# What are the XSLT processor for .NET?

Tags: .net, xslt

I'd like people's opinion on the "best" XSLT processor for .NET, but what are the good options for processing XSLT in .NET?  What do you use and how well does it serve you?

Comment: "Best" needs more definition.  What characteristics would you want to compare in order to establish "Best"?

Comment: Well, in my case I was looking (recently, specifically) for equivalent functions of string replacement and "select distinct" (as in SQL), for example. Things of that ilk. Previously I was very happy with XslCompiledTransform, but found it lacking more recently.

Comment: @Matt: Do you need the XSL to be independant of the implementation.  E.g., do you need the XSL to be able run on a non .NET platform also?

Comment: No, I want to be parsing the XSLT on the server side only.

Comment: What version of XSLT? What is "best"? Very subjective if not a duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want XSLT 2.0 then your best bet is probably [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/). It's written by Michael Kay, who was editor of the XSLT 2.0 specification and was joint editor of the XPath 2.0 specification.

Answer (score 4):

I just use .NET's own `XslCompiledTransform`.  Works fine. Never considered finding a different one.

Comment: As I understand it, that's an implementation of XPath1.0 and doesn't have some of the much improved functions of XPath2.0..? 
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/03/20/xpath2.html

Comment: @Matt: Its always a good idea to include in your question such details as "I want to use XPath 2.0" features.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am a developer of [XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp.com/).

[XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp.com/) is a XSLT 2 and XQuery processor written entirely in .NET.

Comment: I use XQSharp, but [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288233/is-there-an-xslt-2-0-library-for-net) answers in a row plus the subjective "best" califications makes this a spam flagging candidate.

Comment: Point taken.  I have toned down this answer and made my bias more obvious.  I do personally believe that this is a helpful answer though, as our product meets the needs of the OP.